# guile emacs integration update?

Tags: elisp

Is [Guile Emacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GuileEmacs), the project to integrate a guile-based elisp interpreter, still alive?

It was making headway a few years ago, and seemed like a promising project.  Is it on hold because of lack of interest or time?  Or is it awaiting a maturation of the guile language itself?

Comment: This question is intensely tied to the context of the current time; its answers may no longer be valid years in the future. How are questions like this handled?

Comment: That goes for lots of kinds of question, though. Answers relating to a current version of Emacs might not be valid years in the future. Everything here is time-stamped, so no one will be confused in the future about when the information was current.